# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im using the code as below to classify multiple images in a folder and facing an mentioned below. This is as per the tutorial tensorflow for poets.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

# change this as you see fit
image_dir = "/home/shri/Desktop/tf_files/test"

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_dir, 'rb').read()

image = Image.open(image_dir)
image_array = image.convert('RGB')

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
               in tf.gfile.GFile("/root/tf_files/output_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/root/tf_files/output_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_array})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

and the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "label_image3.py", line 8, in <module>
        image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_dir, 'rb').read()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 125, in read
        pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status))
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
        self.gen.next()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
        pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: /home/shri/Desktop/tf_files/test
```

Can someone please let me know if something is wrong in the code and how do i fix it. I also want to get the out put in the an excel sheet.

Regards,
Shri

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Comment: yes. that is the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to open a directory, you give the path to a directory and then try to open it as a file using FastGFile

```
# change this as you see fit
image_dir = "/home/shri/Desktop/tf_files/test"

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_dir, 'rb').read()
```

Comment: How do I fix it and classify all the images in the directory?

Comment: I suggest you look at example code and tutorials. Stackoverflow is here to answer questions not write your code for you